# Proper yet different pronunciation of "domicile"

Tags: pronunciation

According to the [google search I've done](https://www.google.se/search?q=definition+domicile&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=_QitWfaUEe6O6AT24qSACg) the pronunciation of *domicile* might differ and be either *ee* or *ay* on the last syllable.

Is it a *tomayto* versus *tomaato* kind of situation, or is it geographically (or otherwise, in which case how) dependent?

Comment: I have never heard "domiseel". I don't know who says it, but I suspect it is people who do not really have the word in their active vocabulary, and regard it as foreign

Comment: Your question "Is it tomayto versus tomaato kind of situation or is it geographically (or otherwise, in which case how) dependent?" seems to pre-suppose that the tomayto/tomaato distinction isn't geographic.  Actually, it is.  It is "tomaato" for the vast majority of Brits and "tomayto" for the vast majority of Americans - and even the exceptions are often associated with particular regions; e.g. Merriam-Webster says of the "tomaato" pronunciation, "chiefly in Britain, eastern New England, northeastern Virginia, and sometimes elsewhere in cultivated speech".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the sources I have checked only show the following two options for the pronunciation of the final syllable of *domicile*: /sɪl/ (as in "sill") or /saɪl/ (as in "sile"). No "seel" /siːl/ or "sail" /seɪl/ (which is how I would interpret *ee* and *ay*).

Either one seems fine to me, as an American English speaker. The word comes from French *domicile,* which was taken from Latin *[dŏmĭcĭlĭum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=domicilium).* The Oxford English Dictionary says that in the past, some prescriptivists such as John Walker have used Latin vowel quantity as a guide to the pronunication of words ending in *-ile* in English, giving /ɪl/ in words from Latin *-ĭlus* and /aɪl/ in words from Latin *-īlus.* This would favor /ɪl/ in *domicile.* However, this is not really a current practice. Also, the French form with a final silent "e" might provide some historical basis for an English pronunciation with "long i" (/aɪ/).

In modern pronunciation, /ɪl/ and /aɪl/ are distributed without much correspondence to the etymology, and are often in free variation even for a particular word.

In contemporary British English, there is apparently a greater preference for /aɪl/ than there is in contemporary American English.

Some of the sources I looked at also show a variant pronunciation of "domicile" with a "long o" /oʊ/ in the first syllable. I just thought I'd mention it, but I wouldn't recommend using this pronunciation, as it is somewhat more irregular than the one with a "short o" (/ɒ/ or /ɑ/, depending on if you are speaking British or American English). Typically, a single vowel letter other than "u" is pronounced "short" in an antepenultimate stressed syllable.